# publish a project with a database that resides in server and gets updated monthly

Tags: database, winforms, publishing

I have written a Winforms project that utilizes an MS Access database.  When I wrote the project I stored the database locally for testing purposes.  My testing is completed and I want to publish the project.

I need to make a change in where the database resides. Also, the application will be run from the same server that the database will reside on.

I can see two references in my project to the file path of my database.  The first is within the code itself - 
`Dim con As New OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("WindowsApplication1.My.MySettings.ConnectionString1").ConnectionString)`

The second is within the app config - `<add name="WindowsApplication1.My.MySettings.ConnectionString1"
      connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\VulnScanData.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=********"
      providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />`

My database will reside on the D:\ drive of the server.  Do I reference the local drive letter or use a UNC path such as \\server\share in my App.config file?

I was able to publish my app so that it runs on my local pc with no issues.  I just want to be sure I understand how to change it for running from the server.

I figured this out from further testing.  Just use the local drive letter.

Comment: I am not a professional developer, just a sysadmin.  This is my very first app I have tried to publish.

Comment: No further questions.  I consider this issue resolved.